# Print the output on same line

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I execute the command ifconfig eth1 on the terminal on a linux machine, and want the output on the same line.

Eg:Observed:

```
[root@host ~]# ifconfig eth1
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
```

What I want is:

```
[root@host ~]# ifconfig eth1 eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
```

i.e I want to remove the initial newline from the output.

Comment: why do you want them on the same line?

Comment: That newline is _not_ part of the commands output! It is part of the interactive way you _enter the command_!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
printf '\033[A\033[29C'; ifconfig eth0
```

But you would need to replace the `29` with the position where you want the output to be printed (`\033[A` moves the cursor up one line, `\033[50C` moves the cursor to the right `29` times.

Comment: Just a minor thing, I usually type `\033` instead of `\e` for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could execute like this:

```
$ echo $(ifconfig eth0)
```

where the initial $ is ment to be your shell's prompt. For some reason this way all the newlines are removed and the output of "ifconfig eth0" (which is executed in a subshell) is printed on one line.

Comment: With a `-n` flag any empty lines could also be removed.